# How to write to Firestore document from Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am trying to make a cloud function.
Whenever i try to hit the endpoint I get `500 Internal Server Error`
[Postman Response Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwXvN.png)

I've checked logs for firebase functions and i don't see any information there too.
It just says "Function Crashed" without any further information.

I've also checked for any typos and mismatch in the Firestore database structure but it all looks fine to me.

This is the code for firebase function which i uploaded on my Firebase Project.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { error } = require('firebase-functions/lib/logger');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.addEvent = functions.region('asia-east2').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        var db = admin.firestore();
        var write = db.collection("Colleges")
        .doc(req.body.college)
        .collection("events")
        .doc(req.body.event.id)
        .set({
            id: req.body.event.id,
            admin: req.body.event.admin,
            event_state: req.body.event.event_state,
            name: req.body.event.name,
            poster_url: req.body.event.poster_url,
            start_date_time: req.body.event.start,
            end_date_time: req.body.event.end,
            location: req.body.event.location,
            short_desc: req.body.event.shortDesc,
            long_desc: req.body.event.longDesc,
            contacts: req.body.event.contacts,
            links: req.body.event.links,
        });
        return res.send(write);
    }
    else
        return res.sendStatus(403);
});
```

This is the body of the POST Request which i sent from Postman

```
{
    "college": "college_name",
    "event": {
        "id": 1234,
        "admin": "admin",
        "event_state": 2,
        "name": "Event Name",
        "poster_url": "test",
        "start": "Date Time",
        "end": "Date Time",
        "location": "auditorium",
        "shortDesc": "lorem ipsum short",
        "longDesc": "lorem ipsum long",
        "contatcs": [
            {
                "tag": "Name Tag",
                "contact": 12345678
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "tag": "Link Tag",
                "link": 123456784
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Firestore Structure is Something like

```
    -Colleges (Collection)
       |
       |
        -Document 
             |
              -events(Collection)
                  |
                   -Event Documents (Document which i want to write to ,from the firebase function)
```

Comment: Please do not add error description as image. Add the text directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your event id in your payload is a `number` and Firestore documents ids must be strings. So you either, use `.doc(req.body.event.id.toString())` or you send your event id as string in your payload `id: "1234"`.

Also, consider refactoring your code following [Firebase guidelines](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_existing_express_apps) to handle the POST method.